# Working with the task scheduler 1.0 COM API

Tags: windows, com, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to write a simple program in VC++ which will just initialize the task scheduler. I'm following the [example suggested at the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446829(VS.85).aspx), but I get unresolved symbol errors from the linker.

The error is on this line:

```
 hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTaskScheduler,
                           NULL,
                           CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                           IID_ITaskScheduler,
                           (void **) &pITS);
```

The error I get is:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol `_CLSID_CTaskScheduler`

Same error for `_IID_ITaskScheduler`. I have the relevant header files included. Do I need to add a dependency to any other DLL as well?

Thanks,

Rohit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found it out on my own. You need to add the mstask.lib as an additional dependency. Go to Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies and add mstask.lib. The linker error should go away.

Comment: Were you able to run the scheduler. If yes, can you share the code with me? I am getting an error while running the task. The error is: unable to establish existance of the account specified task scheduler.